# Android for loop not working in main thread

Tags: java, android, for-loop, rotation

i try to rotate image. i used runnable to rotate image,i wrote for loop and i want to rotate image inside for loop
this is a my source

```
public void rotateimages(final View myView) {
    myHandler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            double k = 30;

            double speed = Math.PI / k;
            for (alpa = 0; alpa < (Math.PI * 6 + res * 2 * Math.PI / 5); alpa += speed) {

                myView.setRotation((float) (myView.getRotation() - alpa));

                Log.e("alpa values", String.valueOf(alpa));

                k = Math.min(k + 0.2, 240);
                speed = Math.PI / k;
                myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); 
            }
            // rotateimages();
        }

    };

    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 180);
}
```

when i run my app i can rotate only one time.what is a wrong in my code? if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: how did you get the value of currentIteration ?

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski sorry i mistekade.i updated my source

Comment: Are you ok with setting a rotation bigger than 360? If not, do `myView.setRotation((myView.getRotation() + size) % 360);`

Comment: @viviano I am not Android expert but can you explain this line  myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size);? why u did not use variable i in it?

Comment: Why the loop ? Add size * 10 to getRotation()

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski it meand to rotate image 10 degree in for loop.

Comment: @viviano this line  myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size); does not have any 10 in it? or does it? to me it just run this line ten times but does it mean 10 degree?

Comment: just use ViewPropertyAnimator

Comment: @ Kick Buttowski simple i want to rotate my view 10th times.but in click i can rotate only one times.if i click again can rotate and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to loop , you need to define this 'runnable' loop again itself
 edit your code to:

```
myHandler = new Handler();
count = 0;
public void rotateImage(final View myView, final int size) {


    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            count++;
            myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size);
            if(count == 10){
               myHandler.removeCallBack(runnable );
            }
           myHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1000 means 1 second duration
         }
        };
        myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 180); // 180 is the delay after new runnable is going to called

}
```

How to loop itself, that's mean one code line, or one statement call the event again. Some example:

```
 void nothing(int a){
   if(a> 0)
     nothing(a-1);
   }
```

and call nothing(10). that's all, and avoid some action like:

```
void nothing(int a){
       for(int i =0; i< a;i++) 
         nothing(a-1);                //BIG WRONG
       }
 Do you know your solution?
```

Comment: dumping bunch of code leads your post to be flagged as low quality answer. please explain your answer.

Comment: @kemdo thanks it's working. i updated my source. and i have different for loop.in apla value changed everytime but again rotate working only one time.my code is about to control rotate spead

Comment: @kemdo in your code removeCallBack not working.i can't stop rotation

Comment: are you try my code. I have tested in my device and It run normally, can you explain more clearly

Answer (score -1):

In your for loop, you continually increment myView's rotation with 180.

If the number of iterations in the for loop is divisible with 2, then the resulting rotation will be the same as in the beginning. This is why if you rotate the shape once, it gets flipped and you can see the new rotation, but if you rotate it again, it gets flipped back.

Illustration:

no flip. rotation: 0

```
#
#
# #
```

one flip. rotation: 180

```
# #
  #
  #
```

two flips. rotation: 360

```
#
#
# #
```

To fix your code in the way you supposedly want it:

```
public void rotateImage(final View myView, final int size) {

    myHandler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // include one of the following:

            // Way #1: supports animation more easily
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + 1);
            }

            // Way #2: more performant way of doing it
            myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size);

        }
    };
    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 180);

}
```

Comment: can you please format your post in order to be more readable?